# create/update/delete Firebase Realtime Database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a working method for create/update/delete of user chat messages. I wonder if there is a way to reduce my logic.

```
".write": "(!data.exists() && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid) || (data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid) || (data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid && !newData.exists())"
```

Multiline for readibility

```
(!data.exists() && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid) ||
(data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid) ||
(data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid && !newData.exists())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into `bolt`. https://github.com/firebase/bolt

You can simplify queries, then compile the output.

```
path /somePath {
  path /{uid} {
    read() { isUser(uid) }
    write() { isUser(uid) }
  }
}

function isUser(uid) {
  return auth != null && auth.uid == uid;
}
```

It's really handy - although still in beta, it makes the rules much easier to read and understand.